# URL forwarding with masking using .htaccess configuration

Tags: .htaccess

I have domain and space on separate providers. I have **domain1.com**, when users
type this in browser they should be redirected to **domain2.com/somefolder**.

domain2.com is hosted on the server where i have full control on .htaccess file.
So please provide me the changes to be done on **domain2.com/somefolder's** .htaccess
file

I have tried with

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options All -Indexes
Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^&urlink=(.*) http://$1 [P]
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: @JonLin i got that code from somewhere in internet. i know it is wrong

Comment: Yeah, but it's unclear what you are trying to do, the htaccess file you've posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with masking anything.

Comment: @JonLin Thanks for reply. Can we handle masking in .htaccess file?